# Dynamic programming in java (memoizing multiple key parameters)

Tags: java, hashtable, dynamic-programming

I am doing dynamic programming in java and I came across this problem where the function takes three parameters, two of those are integers, and the third is an array of integers. I know that caching the value of a 1- or 2-parameter function can be implemented using a 1d/2d array. I am thinking of may be using a HashMap but I am trying to look for a nicer way to have those three indices bundled together as a key to the hashmap

Comment: Create a `Key` class that can contains those 3 values?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, using Apache Commons Collections:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MultiKeyMap multiKeyMap = new MultiKeyMap();

    int[] array1 = new int[10];
    int[] array2 = new int[10];

    multiKeyMap.put(13,52,array1, "First");
    multiKeyMap.put(81,22,array2, "Second");

    System.out.println(multiKeyMap.get(81,22,array2));  
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the beauty of it. You can whatever you want as a key

Comment: In your code, ```multiKeyMap.get(81,22,array1)``` returns null. ```array1``` and ```array2``` have same value but different hash code value.

Comment: Of course it returns null; the two arrays are two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class which holds all parameters and add it to the map.
Make sure to also implement `hashCode()` & `equals()`

```
class MemoKey {
    Integer a;
    Integer b;
    Integer[] array;

    public MemoKey(Integer a,Integer b, Integer[] array) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { 
        // implement 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // implement
    }
}
```

Then put this class in the map with your result Object.

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<MemoKey, Object>();

Object result = map.get(memoKey);
if (result == null)
    map.put(memoKey, calcResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **immutable** class accepting two generics and an integer array as a constant type (you can change it to  if you know that other numeric types will be used):

```
public final class CustomKey<F,S> {
private final F firstValue;
private final S secondValue;
private final int[] thirdValue;

public CustomKey(final F firstValue,
                 final S secondValue,
                 final Integer[] thirdValue){
    this.firstValue = firstValue;
    this.secondValue = secondValue;
    this.thirdValue = unboxingArray(thirdValue);
}

public S getSecondValue() {
    return secondValue;
}


public F getFirstValue() {
    return firstValue;
}

public int[] getThirdValue() {
    return thirdValue;
}

private static int[] unboxingArray(final Integer[] array){
    final int[] result = new int[array.length];
    IntStream.range(0,array.length)
            .forEach(index -> result[index] =  array[index]);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    final CustomKey<?, ?> customKey = (CustomKey<?, ?>) o;
    return getFirstValue().equals(customKey.getFirstValue()) 
            && getSecondValue().equals(customKey.getSecondValue()) 
            && Arrays.equals(getThirdValue(), customKey.getThirdValue());

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = getFirstValue().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + getSecondValue().hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + Arrays.hashCode(getThirdValue());
    return result;
}
```

}

Unboxing of Integer array is necessary if you want to be able to compare integers in the array. If you will implement other type, do instanceOf check before unboxing.

Then, load your map as you would with any other key:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    //Assume your Value is a String which does not really matter
    Map<CustomKey<Integer,Integer>,String> customKeyMap =
            new HashMap<>();
    customKeyMap.put(new CustomKey<>(1,2,new Integer[]{1,2,3}),"First Value");
    customKeyMap.put(new CustomKey<>(1,3,new Integer[]{1,2,3}),"Second Value");

    //Can use anonymous instance since equals is implemented
    //Expect Second Value
    System.out.println(customKeyMap.get(new CustomKey<>(1,3,new Integer[]{1,2,3})));
}
```